# My solution for LeetCode problem 235 works well in local but is rejected by LeetCode

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm solving the LeetCode problem [235. Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Search Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-search-tree):

> Given a binary search tree (BST), find the lowest common ancestor (LCA) node of two given nodes in the BST.
>
> According to the [definition of LCA on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor): “The lowest common ancestor is defined between two nodes `p` and `q` as the lowest node in `T` that has both `p` and `q` as descendants (where we allow **a node to be a descendant of itself**).”

My solution I ran in local interpreter is below.

```py
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

root = TreeNode(6)
root.left = TreeNode(2)
root.right = TreeNode(8)
root.left.left = TreeNode(0)
root.left.right = TreeNode(4)
root.left.right.left = TreeNode(3)
root.left.right.right = TreeNode(5)
root.right.left = TreeNode(7)
root.right.right = TreeNode(9)

p = 2
q = 8

class Solution(object):
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root, p, q):
      
      def pathFind(path, node, target):

        path.append(node)
        if node.val == target:
            return path
        elif node.val < target:
            return pathFind(path, node.right, target)
        elif node.val > target:
            return pathFind(path, node.left, target)
        else:
            return None

      path_p = pathFind([], root, p) 
      path_q = pathFind([], root, q)

      idx = 0
      while True:

        if path_p[idx] == path_q[idx]:
          idx += 1
        else:
          break

      return path_p[idx - 1]

print(Solution().lowestCommonAncestor(root, p, q))
```

My code works well for many test cases but, in submission in LeetCode, it does not pass even the base case that I passed in my local interpreter.

For example, when I set `p = 2` and `q = 8` (base case), with the sample BST I constructed in the code above, LeetCode rejects my solution.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root, p, q):
      
      def pathFind(path, node, target):

        path.append(node)
        if node.val == target:
            return path
        elif node.val < target:
            return pathFind(path, node.right, target)
        elif node.val > target:
            return pathFind(path, node.left, target)
        else:
            return None

      path_p = pathFind([], root, p) 
      path_q = pathFind([], root, q)

      idx = 0
      while True:

        if path_p[idx] == path_q[idx]:
          idx += 1
        else:
          break

      return path_p[idx - 1]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There are these issues:

1. A misunderstanding: the parameters `p` and `q` are not *values*, but *nodes*. The code challenge description clearly states *"two given nodes"*. So when calling `pathFind` make sure to pass `p.val` and `q.val` as last argument.
2. When `p` happens to be an ancestor of `q` (or vice versa), the final loop will not find a node that is different, but run in a "list index out of range" error. There needs to be a check whether the index is still valid in *both* lists, if not, return the previous node. One way to achieve this is to use `zip(path_p, path_q)` as that will only visit *pairs*.

Corrected code:

```
class Solution:
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root, p, q):
        def pathFind(path, node, target):
            path.append(node)
            if node.val == target:
                return path
            elif node.val < target:
                return pathFind(path, node.right, target)
            elif node.val > target:
                return pathFind(path, node.left, target)
            else:
                return None

        path_p = pathFind([], root, p.val) 
        path_q = pathFind([], root, q.val)
        for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(path_p, path_q)):
            if a != b:
                return path_p[idx - 1]
        return path_p[idx]
```